# Postgresql SQL GROUP BY time interval with arbitrary accuracy (down to milli seconds)

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have my measurement data stored into the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements(
measured_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
val INTEGER
);
```

I **already** know that using

(a) `date_trunc('hour',measured_at)`

AND

(b) `generate_series`

I would be able to aggregate my data by:

```
microseconds,
milliseconds
.
.
.
```

But is it possible to aggregate the data by 5 minutes or let's say an arbitrary amount of seconds? Is it possible to aggregate measured data by an arbitrary multiple of seconds?

I need the data aggregated by different time resolutions to feed them into a FFT or an AR-Model in order to see possible seasonalities.

Answer (score 60):

You can generate a table of "buckets" by adding intervals created by generate_series(). This SQL statement will generate a table of five-minute buckets for the first day (the value of `min(measured_at)`) in your data.

```
select 
  (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ( n    || ' minutes')::interval start_time,
  (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ((n+5) || ' minutes')::interval end_time
from generate_series(0, (24*60), 5) n
```

Wrap *that* statement in a common table expression, and you can join and group on it as if it were a base table.

```
with five_min_intervals as (
  select 
    (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ( n    || ' minutes')::interval start_time,
    (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ((n+5) || ' minutes')::interval end_time
  from generate_series(0, (24*60), 5) n
)
select f.start_time, f.end_time, avg(m.val) avg_val 
from measurements m
right join five_min_intervals f 
        on m.measured_at >= f.start_time and m.measured_at < f.end_time
group by f.start_time, f.end_time
order by f.start_time
```

Grouping by an arbitrary number of seconds is similar--use `date_trunc()`.

---

A more general use of generate_series() lets you avoid guessing the upper limit for five-minute buckets. In practice, you'd probably build this as a view or a function. You might get better performance from a base table.

```
select 
  (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ( n    || ' minutes')::interval start_time,
  (select min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + ((n+5) || ' minutes')::interval end_time
from generate_series(0, ((select max(measured_at)::date - min(measured_at)::date from measurements) + 1)*24*60, 5) n;
```

Comment: `generate_series(timestamp, timestamp, interval)` suits this case better, see Bill's answer below for why.

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy: We don't know whether `generate_series(timestamp, timestamp, interval)` was a better choice for this 4-year-old question. There's no version information in the question. Timestamp arguments were introduced in 8.4; earlier versions were still widely used in 2012. Even today, some derived products like GreenPlum and Amazon Redshift don't support timestamp arguments in `generate_series`.

Comment: This solution makes interval boundaries move depending on the min and max timestamp available in the data. It may not work for a dynamic (aka "live") chart because the labels along the X axis will change. If this is the case, absolute intervals  (not bound to min/max data) may work better.

Answer (score 16):

Catcall has a great answer. My example of using it demonstrates having fixed buckets - in this case 30 minute intervals starting at midnight. It also shows that there can be one extra bucket generated in Catcall's first version and how to eliminate it. I wanted exactly 48 buckets in a day. In my problem, observations have separate date and time columns and I want to average the observations within a 30 minute period across the month for a number of different services.

```
with intervals as (
    select
        (n||' minutes')::interval as start_time, 
        ((n+30)|| ' minutes')::interval as end_time
    from generate_series(0, (23*60+30), 30) n
)
select i.start_time, o.service, avg(o.o)
from
observations o right join intervals i
on o.time >= i.start_time and o.time < i.end_time
where o.date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31'
group by i.start_time, i.end_time, o.service
order by i.start_time
```

Answer (score 16):

How about

```
SELECT MIN(val), 
EXTRACT(epoch FROM measured_at) / EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '5 min') AS int 
FROM measurements 
GROUP BY int
```

where '5 min' can be any expression supported by INTERVAL

Comment: To make time buckets: `ROUND((EXTRACT(epoch FROM "when") / EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '5 min')) * EXTRACT(epoch FROM INTERVAL '5 min')) AS "my_time_bucket"`

Answer (score 13):

From PostgreSQL v14 on, you can use the [`date_bin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function for that:

```
SELECT date_bin(
          INTERVAL '5 minutes',
          measured_at,
          TIMESTAMPTZ '2000-01-01'
       ),
       sum(val)
FROM measurements
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 10):

The following will give you buckets of any size, even if they don't aline well with a nice minute/hour/whatever boundary. The value "300" is for a 5 minute grouping, but any value can be substituted:

```
select measured_at, 
       val, 
       (date_trunc('seconds', (measured_at - timestamptz 'epoch') / 300) * 300 + timestamptz 'epoch') as aligned_measured_at
from measurements;
```

You can then use whatever aggregate you need around "val", and use "group by aligned_measured_at" as required.

Answer (score 7):

This is based on Mike Sherrill's answer, except that it uses timestamp intervals instead of separate start/end columns.

```
with intervals as (
    select tstzrange(s, s + '5 minutes') das_interval
    from (select generate_series(min(lower(time_range)), max(upper(time_rage)), '5 minutes') s
          from your_table) x)
select das_interval, your_table.*
from   your_table
right join intervals on time_range && das_interval
order by das_interval;
```

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to look at the past 24 hours of data and count things in hourly increments.  I started Cat Recall's solution, which is pretty slick.  It's bound to the data, though, rather than just what's happened in the past 24H.  So I refactored and ended up with something pretty close to Julian's solution, but with more CTE.  So it's sort of the marriage of the 2 answers.

```
WITH interval_query AS (
    SELECT (ts ||' hour')::INTERVAL AS hour_interval
    FROM generate_series(0,23) AS ts
), time_series AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('hour', now()) + INTERVAL '60 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', now()) / 60.0) - interval_query.hour_interval AS start_time
    FROM interval_query
), time_intervals AS (
    SELECT start_time, start_time + '1 hour'::INTERVAL AS end_time
    FROM time_series ORDER BY start_time
), reading_counts AS (
    SELECT f.start_time, f.end_time, br.minor, count(br.id) readings
    FROM beacon_readings br
    RIGHT JOIN time_intervals f
                    ON br.reading_timestamp >= f.start_time AND br.reading_timestamp < f.end_time AND br.major = 4
    GROUP BY f.start_time, f.end_time, br.minor
    ORDER BY f.start_time, br.minor
)
SELECT * FROM reading_counts
```

Note that any additional limiting I wanted in the final query needed to be done in the `RIGHT JOIN`. I'm not suggesting this is necessarily the best (or even a good approach), but it is something I'm running with (at least at the moment) in a dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

The [Timescale extension](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb) for PostgreSQL gives the ability to group by arbitrary time intervals. The function is called `time_bucket()` and has the same syntax as the `date_trunc()` function but takes an interval instead of a time precision as first parameter. [Here](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/analytics/time_bucket/#time-bucket) you can find its API Docs. This is an example:

```sql
SELECT
  time_bucket('5 minutes', observation_time) as bucket,
  device_id,
  avg(metric) as metric_avg,
  max(metric) - min(metric) as metric_spread
FROM
  device_readings
GROUP BY bucket, device_id;
```

You may also take a look at the [continuous aggregate views](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts/continuous-aggregates/#an-introductory-example) if you want the *'grouped by an interval'* views be updated automatically with new ingested data and if you want to query these views on a frequent basis. This can save you a lot of resources and will make your queries a lot faster.

Comment: This is a commercial product

Comment: @geotheory Only their managed cloud service. The extension is open-sourced under the  apache 2.0 license. So I don't see a problem. You don't need to use their managed service.

Comment: I thought the same thing.  @TomBöttger you should link to the open source plugin instead of the product's homepage.

Comment: Thanks @danielricecodes I have updated the links and now use the github instead of the commercial website link

Answer (score 3):

I've taken a synthesis of all the above to try and come up with something slightly easier to use;

```
create or replace function interval_generator(start_ts timestamp with TIME ZONE, end_ts timestamp with TIME ZONE, round_interval INTERVAL)
    returns TABLE(start_time timestamp with TIME ZONE, end_time timestamp with TIME ZONE) as $$
BEGIN
return query
        SELECT
            (n)       start_time,
            (n + round_interval) end_time
        FROM generate_series(date_trunc('minute', start_ts), end_ts, round_interval) n;
END
$$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This function is a timestamp abstraction of [Mikes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12046382/252556), which (IMO) makes things a little cleaner, especially if you're generating queries on the client end.

Also using an inner join gets rid of the sea of `NULL`s that appeared previously.

```
with intervals as (select * from interval_generator(NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours' , NOW(), '30 seconds'::INTERVAL))
select f.start_time, m.session_id, m.metric, min(m.value) min_val, avg(m.value) avg_val, max(m.value) max_val
from ts_combined as m
inner JOIN intervals f
    on m.time >= f.start_time and m.time < f.end_time
GROUP BY f.start_time, f.end_time, m.metric, m.session_id
ORDER BY f.start_time desc
```

(Also for my purposes I added in a few more aggregation fields)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you can `extract(epoch from measured_at)` and go from that?