# Group by data intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, nosql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I have a single table which stores bandwidth usage on the network over a period of time. One column will contain the date time (primary key) and another column will record the bandwidth. Data is recorded every minute. We will have other columns recording other data at that moment in time.

If the user requests the data on 15 minute intervals (within a 24 hour period given start and end date), is it possible with a single query to get the data I require or would I have to write a stored procedure/cursor to do this? Users may then request 5 minute intervals data etc.

I will most likely be using Postgres but are there other NOSQL options which would be better?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT ts, (random()*100)::int AS bandwidth
   FROM   generate_series('2012-09-01', '2012-09-04', '1 minute'::interval) ts
   )

SELECT date_trunc('hour', ts) AS hour_stump
      ,(extract(minute FROM ts)::int / 15) AS min15_slot
      ,count(*) AS rows_in_timeslice               -- optional
      ,sum(bandwidth) AS sum_bandwidth
FROM   t
WHERE  ts >= '2012-09-02 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz -- user's time range
AND    ts <  '2012-09-03 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz -- careful with borders 
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

The [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) `t` provides data like your table might hold: one timestamp `ts` per minute with a `bandwidth` number. (You don't need that part, you work with your table instead.)

Here is a very similar solution for a very similar question - with detailed explanation how this particular aggregation works:

- [date_trunc 5 minute interval in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165827/date-trunc-5-minute-interval-in-postgresql/12167385#12167385)

Here is a similar solution for a similar question concerning *running* sums - with detailed explanation and links for the various functions used:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

#### Additional question in comment

```
WITH -- same as above ...

SELECT DISTINCT ON (1,2)
       date_trunc('hour', ts) AS hour_stump
      ,(extract(minute FROM ts)::int / 15) AS min15_slot
      ,bandwidth AS bandwith_sample_at_min15
FROM   t
WHERE  ts >= '2012-09-02 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz
AND    ts <  '2012-09-03 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz
ORDER  BY 1, 2, ts DESC;
```

Retrieves *one* un-aggregated sample per 15 minute interval - from the *last available row* in the window. This will be the 15th minute if the row is not missing. Crucial parts are `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY`.
More information about the used technique here:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thank you so much. Time to study, I had no idea this was at all possible.

Comment: How do I get the actual value on the 15th minute boundary rather than the sum(bandwidth)?

Comment: @JD: Define "on the 15th minute boundary". The minute before or after? And you mean the un-aggregated value from that single row, right?

Answer (score 6):

```
select
    date_trunc('hour', d) + 
    (((extract(minute from d)::integer / 5 * 5)::text) || ' minute')::interval
    as "from",
    date_trunc('hour', d) + 
    ((((extract(minute from d)::integer / 5 + 1) * 5)::text) || ' minute')::interval
    - '1 second'::interval
    as "to",
    sum(random() * 1000) as bandwidth
from 
    generate_series('2012-01-01', '2012-01-31', '1 minute'::interval) s(d)
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
;
```

That for 5 minutes ranges. For 15 minutes divide by 15.

Comment: Wow, thank you but where do I start? generate_series() is a ? What does the table look like? Sorry, pretty new to PostGres so please bare with me.

Comment: @JD: The name of the software is `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. [Details here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). [PostgreSQL's manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/) is of outstanding quality. Follow the links (in the related answers I link to in my answer!) for details and deep links into the manual.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Turns out, you answer already has most of what I posted, except for explanation. +1 for being first.