# Selecting an average of records grouped by 5 minute periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I'm having a slight issue. I have a PostgreSQL table with such format

```
time (datetime)     | players (int) | servers (int)
---------------------------------------------------
2013-12-06 13:40:01 | 80            | 20
2013-12-06 13:41:13 | 78            | 21
etc.
```

I would like to group them by 5 minute periods and get an average of the group as a single value, so there will be 20% of the records, each containing an average of ~5 numbers, with time set to the first time value in the group. I have no idea how to do this in PgSQL. So the result would be:

```
2013-12-06 13:40:01 | avg of players on :40, :41, :42, :43, :44 | same with servers
2013-12-06 13:45:05 | avg of players on :45, :46, :47, :48, :49 | same with servers
2013-12-06 13:50:09 | avg of players on :50, :51, :52, :53, :54 | same with servers
2013-12-06 13:55:12 | avg of players on :55, :56, :57, :58, :59 | same with servers
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
SELECT grid.t5
     , min(t."time") AS min_time
--   , array_agg(extract(min FROM t."time")) AS 'players_on'  -- optional
     , avg(t.players) AS avg_players
     , avg(t.servers) AS avg_servers
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min("time")
                        , max("time")
                        , interval '5 min') AS t5
   FROM   tbl
   ) grid
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t."time" >= grid.t5
                 AND t."time" <  grid.t5 + interval '5 min'
GROUP  BY grid.t5
ORDER  BY grid.t5;
```

The subquery `grid` produces one row for every 5 minutes from minimum to maximum `"time"` in your table.

`LEFT JOIN` back to the table slicing data in 5-min intervals.  *Include* the lower bound, *exclude* the upper border.
To drop 5-min slots where nothing happened, use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

To have your grid-times start at 0:00, 5:00 etc, round down the `min("time")` in `generate_series()`.

Related:

- [Group by data intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623358/group-by-data-intervals/12624551#12624551)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Aside: I wouldn't use "time" as identifier. It's a [reserved word in standard SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and a function / type name in Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it should group minutes 0-4, 5-9, 10-14 and so on...

```
SELECT MIN(time), AVG(Players), AVG(Servers)
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', time),
    FLOOR(datepart('minute', time)/12)
```

EDIT: Changed the grouping to hour first and then to the `Floor` of minutes. I Think this should work.

Comment: Produces one row per minute.

Comment: Update: Works, but now you need to wrap the first column in an aggregate function.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter With my previous query I overlooked that I was grouping until the minute component of time. Thanks for correcting me. Can't we just `SELECT` MIN(time) and remove the `date_trunc` in SELECT, though your answer would be a more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, min(time) as 1st column works. Produces a similar result like my query (with a JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN). I'd expect this one to be slower, though, due to more calculations per row. Still, +1.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for reaffirming that though it may be inefficient, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select datepart('year', time) as StartYear, datepart('month', time) as StartMonth,
    datepart('day', time) as StartDay, datepart('hour', time) as StartHour,
    floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5 as StartMinute,
    avg(case when datepart('minute', time) = floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5 then players else null end) as Zero,
    avg(case when datepart('minute', time) = floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5+1 then players else null end) as One,
    avg(case when datepart('minute', time) = floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5+2 then players else null end) as Two,
    avg(case when datepart('minute', time) = floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5+3 then players else null end) as Three,
    avg(case when datepart('minute', time) = floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5+4 then players else null end) as Four,
from MyTable
group by datepart('year', time), datepart('month', time),
    datepart('day', time), datepart('hour', time),
    floor(datepart('minute', time)/5)*5
```

Comment: I think he wants the players from minute 0 through 4 grouped together, similarly minute 5 to 10 and so on.

Comment: @user2989408 That's exactly what I meant.