# GROUP BY next months over N years

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregation

I need to aggregate amounts grouped by "horizon" 12 next months over 5 year:
*assuming we are **2015-08-15***

```
SUM amount from  0 to 12 next months (from 2015-08-16 to 2016-08-15)
SUM amount from 12 to 24 next months (from 2016-08-16 to 2017-08-15)
SUM amount from 24 to 36 next months ...
SUM amount from 36 to 48 next months
SUM amount from 48 to 60 next months
```

Here is a [fiddled](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af71d/1) dataset example:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | date       | amount |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-09-01 |     10 |
|  2 | 2015-10-01 |     10 |
|  3 | 2016-10-01 |     10 |
|  4 | 2017-06-01 |     10 |
|  5 | 2018-06-01 |     10 |
|  6 | 2019-05-01 |     10 |
|  7 | 2019-04-01 |     10 |
|  8 | 2020-04-01 |     10 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Here is the expected result:

```
+---------+--------+
| horizon | amount |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |     20 |
|       2 |     20 |
|       3 |     10 |
|       4 |     20 |
|       5 |     10 |
+---------+--------+
```

How can I get these 12 next months grouped "horizons" ?

---

I tagged *PostgreSQL* but I'm actually using an ORM so it's just to find the idea. (by the way I don't have access to the date formatting functions)

Comment: Subtract 8.5 months and group by year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would split by 12 months time frame and group by this:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(
      (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now()))
        / EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '12 month')
    ) + 1 AS "horizon",
  SUM(amount) AS "amount"
FROM dataset 
GROUP BY horizon
ORDER BY horizon;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af71d/55)

Inspired by: [Postgresql SQL GROUP BY time interval with arbitrary accuracy (down to milli seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045600/postgresql-sql-group-by-time-interval-with-arbitrary-accuracy-down-to-milli-sec)

Comment: The most simple and smart answer for me

Comment: Kudos and +1 for providing link to inspiration.

Comment: Note that (a / b) - (c / b) = (a - c) / b. The latter is almost twice as fast to calculate. Also note that `epoch from interval '12 month'` gives you seconds equal to 365.25 days. Depending on which year you are in and which you are comparing to (leap year or not) the result may be a day off in either direction.

Comment: Thx for the factorization, it also makes it simpler, I have updated the answer and the fiddle according

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps CTE?

```
WITH RECURSIVE grps AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS Horizon, (date '2015-08-15') + interval '1' day AS FromDate, (date '2015-08-15') + interval '1' year AS ToDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Horizon + 1, ToDate + interval '1' day AS FromDate, ToDate + interval '1' year
  FROM grps WHERE Horizon < 5
)
SELECT 
  Horizon, 
  (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM dataset WHERE date BETWEEN g.FromDate AND g.ToDate) AS SumOfAmount
FROM 
  grps g
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af71d/40)

Comment: An amazing solution! Too bad it is so hideously complex while there is a rather straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather simply:

```
SELECT horizon, sum(amount) AS amount
FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS s(horizon)
JOIN dataset ON "date" >= current_date + (horizon - 1) * interval '1 year'
             AND "date" < current_date + horizon * interval '1 year'
GROUP BY horizon
ORDER BY horizon;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a union and an aggregate function:

```
select 1 as horizon, 
       sum(amount) amount
from the_table
where date >= current_date 
  and date < current_date + interval '12' month
union all
select 2 as horizon, 
       sum(amount) amount
where date >= current_date + interval '12' month
  and date < current_date + interval '24' month
union all 
select 3 as horizon, 
       sum(amount) amount
where date >= current_date + interval '24' month
  and date < current_date + interval '36' month
... and so on ...
```

But I don't know, how to do that with an obfuscation layer (aka ORM) but I'm sure it supports (or it *should*) aggregation and unions.

This could easily be wrapped up into a PL/PgSQL function where you pass the "horizon" and the SQL is built dynamically so that all you need to call is something like: `select * from sum_horizon(5)` where `5` indicates the number of years.

---

<sup>Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's a reserved word, but more importantly because it doesn't *document* the meaning of the column. Is it a "release date"? A "due date"? An "order date"?</sup>

Comment: `JOIN generate_series(1, 5) AS s(h)` and then `current_date + s.h * interval '1 year'` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need intervals from current date to this day next year and so on, I would query this like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > now()
AND date < (now() + '12 months'::INTERVAL)
UNION
SELECT 2 AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > (now() + '12 months'::INTERVAL)
AND date < (now() + '24 months'::INTERVAL) 
UNION
SELECT 3 AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > (now() + '24 months'::INTERVAL)
AND date < (now() + '36 months'::INTERVAL)
UNION
SELECT 4 AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > (now() + '36 months'::INTERVAL)
AND date < (now() + '48 months'::INTERVAL)
UNION
SELECT 5 AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > (now() + '48 months'::INTERVAL)
AND date < (now() + '60 months'::INTERVAL)
ORDER BY horizon;
```

You can generalize it and make something like this using additional variable:

```
SELECT number AS horizon, SUM(amount) FROM dataset
WHERE date > (now() + ((number - 1) * '12 months'::INTERVAL))
AND date < (now() + (number * '12 months'::INTERVAL));
```

Where `number` is an integer from range `[1,5]`

Here is what I get from the Fiddle:

```
| horizon | sum |
|---------|-----|
|       1 |  20 |
|       2 |  20 |
|       3 |  10 |
|       4 |  20 |
|       5 |  10 |
```

Comment: Your `number` would come from `JOIN generate_series(1, 5) AS s(number)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
id,
sum(case when date>=current_date and date<current_date+interval 1 year then amount else 0 end) as year1,
sum(case when date>=current_date+interval 1 year and date<current_date+interval 2 year then amount else 0 end) as year2,
sum(case when date>=current_date+interval 2 year and date<current_date+interval 3 year then amount else 0 end) as year3,
sum(case when date>=current_date+interval 3 year and date<current_date+interval 4 year then amount else 0 end) as year4,
sum(case when date>=current_date+interval 4 year and date<current_date+interval 5 year then amount else 0 end) as year5
from table
group by id
```